# SQL Select SQL Statement output + ( )

Tags: sql

Table Name: aa_company

```
Column_A    Column_B    Column_C
ABC         0001        abc@gmail.com

BCD         0002        bcd@gmail.com

CDE         0003        cde@gmail.com


Select Column_A, Column_B, Column_C
FROM aa_company;
```

if I want the output result add one more column, how can i do it?

```
Column_A    Column_B    Column_C          Column_D
ABC         0001        abc@gmail.com     ABC (0001)

BCD         0002        bcd@gmail.com     BCD (0002)

CDE         0003        cde@gmail.com     CDE (0003)
```

Comment: `Select Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_A + ' (' + Column_B + ')'
FROM aa_company;`

Comment: @artm : First, please post your comment as an answer. site policy [clearly states](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) you should not use the comments to answer questions. Second, Please note that not all databases supports `+` as a string concatenation operator. ANSI-SQL uses `||` (and so does Oracle).

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's why I left it as a comment, not sure which DBMS OP is using so didn't know if `+` would work or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE1
    ([COLUMN_A] VARCHAR(3), [COLUMN_B] VARCHAR(50), [COLUMN_C] VARCHAR(13))
;

INSERT INTO #TABLE1
    ([COLUMN_A], [COLUMN_B], [COLUMN_C])
VALUES
    ('ABC', '0001', 'ABC@GMAIL.COM'),
    ('BCD', '0002', 'BCD@GMAIL.COM'),
    ('CDE', '0003', 'CDE@GMAIL.COM')
;
```

using `concat` function

```
   SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C,CONCAT(COLUMN_A,'('+COLUMN_B+')') AS COLUMN_D FROM #TABLE1
```

or
using + operator

```
   Select Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_A + ' (' + Column_B + ')'  COLUMN_D  FROM #TABLE1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the concat funcation you can achieve the required result.

```
Select Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, 
concat(column_A,' ('+column_B+')') as Column_D
from aa_company
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Column_A, Column_B, Column_C,Column_A + '('+Column_B+')'
FROM aa_company;
```

Here the Column B seems to be numeric so you need to convert it into type varchar so the query would be like

```
Select Column_A, Column_B, Column_C,Column_A + '('+CONVERT(varchar(10),Column_B)+')'
FROM aa_company;
```

to give header to the new column you can write as

```
Select Column_A, Column_B, Column_C,Column_A + '('+CONVERT(varchar(10),Column_B)+')' as Column_D
FROM aa_company;
```